# Git pushes old commit in different branch to new branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I've been struggling with GIT for a while now since it does some weird things.

I have a base commit with the initial code.

Ok next I make a branch do my edits and commit and push:

```
git checkout -b feature/feature1
git commit -m "added feature1"
git push origin feature/feature1
```

Now I do a pull request on that feature.

After that I change branch and update for example:

```
git checkout -b chore/update-framework
git commit -m "updated framework"
git push origin chore/update-framework
```

At this point when I try a pull request on the 2nd push, it contains the first commit with all the feature stuff in it. So all the changed files from that commit are in the new pull request, while the old pull request only contains the feature files.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `git checkout -b <branch>` simply creates a new branch that points at your current `HEAD`. If you want to checkout a different branch, either `git checkout <branch>` (without the `-b`, assumes the branch already exists), or `git checkout -b <newbranchname> <existingcommit-ish>`, which creates a new branch that points to a specific branch head, tag, commit, etc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you did:

```
git checkout -b chore/update-framework
```

You did not checkout on master **before**.

To start a new branch from the commit you want (example with master):

```
git checkout -b chore/update-framework master
```

or:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b chore/update-framework
```

or:

```
git branch chore/update-framework master
git checkout chore/update-framework
```

To correct your mistake, you can do:

```
git rebase --onto master feature/feature1 chore/update-framework
```

Git will pick all your commits of chore/update-framework which are not pointed by feature/feature1, then it will put them onto master and finally update your chore/update-framework branch.

Comment: This seemed to be my issue, except I was making branches on the branches of develop. This fixed it really easy.

Answer (score 5):

I think your issue here comes down to understanding what it means for a commit to be on (or it may be better to say *contained in*) a branch.  This is different in Git than in many traditional version control systems.

In Git, each commit is on (or contained in) *many* branches, at least potentially.  It can be on no branches, 1 branch, 2 branches, and so on.  This is because, in Git, a branch *name* is just a moveable pointer to *one specific commit*.  Think of it more as a yellow sticky note.  Creating a new branch name means grabbing a blank sticky note and writing the name on it, `feature/feature1`.

But where is the note attached?  Well, here it helps a lot to draw (part of) the commit *graph*.

#### Drawing (part of) a commit graph

In Git, each commit "points to" its predecessor(s) (or parent commits).  For a linear chain of commits, this is basically a series of arrows pointing backwards in time:

```
... <- o <- o <- o <- ... <- o
```

Each `o` here represents a commit and each commit points back to its (one) parent.

A merge commit points back to *two* parents, which is in fact what makes it a merge commit.  These are much harder to draw with arrows when restricted to plain text on StackOverflow:

```
           o--o
          /    \
... --o--*      M--o
          \    /
           o--o
```

Imagine arrowheads on all the lines, so that they all point left-ish (up-and-left, or down-and-left, if needed).  `M` here is the merge commit, with its two parents.  I marked one more commit here, commit `*`.  It is *not* a merge commit, but it does have two *children* (two commits that point back to it).  This sometimes makes it more interesting.

In fact, commit `*` is especially interesting *before* we make the merge commit.  Let's draw that (by erasing `M` and some `o`s):

```
           o
          /
... --o--*
          \
           o--o
```

#### Adding branch names to the drawing

This is where branches really come into proper focus.  Let's add names and longer `<--` arrows:

```
           o   <-- bra1
          /
... --o--*
          \
           o--o   <-- bra2
```

Branch `bra1` points to (or, equivalently, is a yellow sticky note pasted onto) the upper tip-most `o` commit, and `bra2` points to the lower tip-most `o`.

That commit we called out as `*` is *on both branches* (as is every commit to its left).

There are two more pieces to this particular puzzle.  One is the name `HEAD`, and the other has to do with what happens when we add new commits and write up new branch names.

#### `HEAD`

The name `HEAD`, in Git, tells us about our current commit and current branch.  The *way* Git does this is almost laughably simple: `HEAD` normally just contains the name of the branch.  Think of it as another sticky note (maybe bright pink, or green, or purple, just to make it obviously a bit different).  It *can* point directly to a commit—that's the "detached HEAD" thing you have no doubt seen—but normally it just has a branch name written on it:

```
           o   <-- HEAD->bra1
          /
... --o--*
          \
           o--o   <-- bra2
```

This means we are on branch `bra1`.

#### Growing a branch

Let's make a new commit while we're on `bra1`.

When making a new commit, Git:

1. Reads `HEAD` (it says `branch bra1`).
2. Reads the commit ID from branch `bra1` (that's some big ugly SHA-1 `a1c397f...` or whatever).
3. Makes a new commit using whatever you've `git add`ed, with your log message, pointing to that parent ID.  The new commit gets a new unique SHA-1 (such as `0bc3112...`).
4. Writes this new number into the current branch, `bra1`.

Step 4 causes `bra1` to point to the new commit, and now we have:

```
           o--o   <-- HEAD->bra1
          /
... --o--*
          \
           o--o   <-- bra2
```

#### Adding a merge commit

Just for completeness, let's look at making a merge commit.

The process of doing the merge itself can be messy, but actually making the merge *commit* is easy: it's just a commit with two parents.  Note that we still are on `bra1`.  We run `git merge bra2`.  Git fires up the merge machinery to do the work in the work-tree.  If there are conflicts, it leaves a mess behind and we have to fix that up manually, but if not, it automatically starts a new commit.

The new commit happens just as before, with one small change.  In step 3, instead of writing *one* parent ID (the one from the existing `bra1`), it writes *two* parent IDs: the first one is the usual one, and the second one is the ID obtained from reading `bra2`.

Step 4 works as usual, writing the new commit's ID into `bra1` (because `HEAD` still says "use branch `bra1`"):

```
           o--o
          /    \
... --o--*      M   <-- HEAD->bra1
          \    /
           o--o   <-- bra2
```

Because `M` is a merge (has two parents), this means that all the commits that used to be exclusively on `bra2` are now on `bra1` as well!

Commit `*` used to be on both branches, and still is.  And, there are still those two post-`*` commits we can get to by starting from `bra2` and working leftwards.

We're only allowed to move left(ish), so starting from `bra2`, we are *not* allowed to move to `M`, which means we cannot get to the top row of commits.  We can only get there by starting there, or starting from `M`.  We are, however, not just allowed, but actually *required*, to follow *all* the parents of a merge like `M`.  So starting from `bra1`, we get `M`, then we get both sides of the branch structure all the way back to commit `*`, and keep going leftward from there.

If you count the nodes, you will see that there are now three commits contained in `bra1` that are not contained in `bra2` ... but all commits contained in `bra2` are contained in `bra1`.

#### OK, so what about creating *new* branches?

Here `HEAD` comes back into play.

You can use `git branch` to *just* create a branch:

```
$ git branch bra3
```

By default, this reads `HEAD` to figure out where we are now.  `HEAD` says `bra1` and `bra1` has `M`'s ID in it.  So this makes `bra3` point to `M`:

```
           o--o
          /    \
... --o--*      M   <-- HEAD->bra1, bra3
          \    /
           o--o   <-- bra2
```

Note that `HEAD` still points where it used to, and no other branch is disturbed either, we just added a new moveable label `bra3`.  If we now move `bra1` or `bra2`, `bra3` continues to point to `M`.

Since `HEAD` still points to `bra1`, new commits will make `bra1` change.

If we use `git checkout -b` to create the new branch, though, we get this instead:

```
           o--o
          /    \
... --o--*      M   <-- bra1, HEAD->bra3
          \    /
           o--o   <-- bra2
```

This looks almost exactly the same.  The difference is that, besides adding the new branch name, we *also* change `HEAD`.  Now it points to `bra3`.

#### Making a new branch that points to something other than the current commit

Let's go back to `git branch`, which just makes the branch and does not change `HEAD`.  The `git branch` command takes one more optional argument:

```
$ git branch bra4 bra2
```

Instead of making `bra4` point to the same commit as `HEAD`, this says "make `bra4` point to the same commit as `bra2`".  So now we have:

```
           o--o
          /    \
... --o--*      M   <-- bra1, HEAD->bra3
          \    /
           o--o   <-- bra2, bra4
```

Now let's `git checkout bra4`, just to see what that does (in terms of the graph—it also checks out the files, of course):

```
$ git checkout bra4

           o--o
          /    \
... --o--*      M   <-- bra1, bra3
          \    /
           o--o   <-- bra2, HEAD->bra4
```

Again, nothing happens to any of the branch labels themselves.  In the graph, we just change where `HEAD` points.

(We could have used the combined form—we already have `bra4` now so it's too late now, but it would have been one command instead of two—by doing `git checkout -b bra4 bra2`.)

#### The bottom line for new branch pointers

This means we get to choose which *commit a new branch points to* whenever we create that new branch.  The *default* is "wherever `HEAD` points", which usually means reading another branch name.  We can make `HEAD` point somewhere useful first, or we can just add that to the branch-creator and make it all happen together.

That leaves one question, and it does not always have a single right answer: where should we point that new branch?

Probably we want to point it to something like `origin/master` or `origin/feature1`.  Sometimes it makes more sense to pick some other starting point, maybe even one with no label pointing to it.

#### Wait, `origin/master` is a label?

Yes, these things are branch labels—moveable pointers to commits—too.  They're just not labels that *you* move.  You let them move when you run `git fetch` (or pull, but pull is just fetch followed by one other step).  In other words, they "track the remote" (you `git fetch origin` and `origin/*` move if needed); so they are *remote-tracking branches*.

When we drew up the graphs above, we probably should have included these labels ... maybe something like this:

```
           o      <-- HEAD->feature1
          /
... --o--*        <-- origin/feature1
          \
           o--o   <-- feature2
```

If you want to make a new `feature3` that grows out from `*` as well, `git checkout -b feature3 origin/feature1` would do that.  Commit `*` would then be contained in *four* branches: `feature1`, `origin/feature1`, `feature2`, and `feature3`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, yes it might be because I'm so used to SVN and other version control that Git makes no sense to me (besides the weird naming sense of commands).